# Define variables in Javascript executing a local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, local, execute

I have a node.js script which involves access tokens.

```
var T = new Twit({
consumer_key:         '...', 
,consumer_secret:      '...'
,access_token:         '...'
,access_token_secret:  '...'
})
```

I want to define this data with a script on the same folder, so I need to call it. Something similar to

```
execfile('keys.py')
```

in Python. I've tried

```
require('./keys.js')
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the file to a variable, as so:

```
var keys = require('./keys.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should export the keys to a JSON file, read its contents with readFileSync and then parse the JSON:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var keysJson = fs.readFileSync("keys.json", "utf8");
var keys = JSON.parse(keysJson);

var T = new Twit(keys);
```

Note that you must pass the encoding ("utf8" in this case) to the readFileSync method, or else it will return a buffer instead of the file contents.